# How to sort data mysql in php syntax

Tags: php, sorting

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\techponya\index.php on line x

```
<?php 
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM artikel WHERE kategori='technews' DESC() LIMIT 5";
$hasil2 = mysql_query($sql2,$dbconn);
while ($techponya = mysql_fetch_array($hasil2)){ 
?>
```

Comment: Your SQL query is wrong. just try to get the query alone working in something like PHPmyAdmin and then insert it into your code. First question you should ask yourself: How should the database know by which column to sort ...

Comment: Are you forced to work with `mysql_*` functions ? Because you should consider using latest secure mysql driver such as `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Comment: Please head to [the manual page for `mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) and scroll down the *do not use this extension* warning to "Example #1". There's a simple usage example.

Comment: What [Alex](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2587185/alex) said :) But best to avoid using [mysql_fetch_array ](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) as it is deprecated, use [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Stop using deprecated (From php 5 version onwards)+removed(From php 7) `mysql_*`. Use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`

2.Use `ORDER BY` along with `DESC`:-

```
<?php 
  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM artikel WHERE kategori='technews' ORDER BY <write your column name here> DESC LIMIT 5";
  $hasil2 = mysql_query($sql2,$dbconn);
  while ($techponya = mysql_fetch_array($hasil2)){
    // do some stuff 
  }
?>
```

3.Also always do error checking code stuff too.

reference:-

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Answer (score 2):

your `mysql_query` is returning an error, to order just use `ORDER BY your_field_name DESC` instead of `DESC()`